# How to handle get requests automatically if template exists (using node.js+express)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm using node.js with express (and EJS as the template language) and would like to know if there is an easy way to automatically handle serving pages matching a given path if a template exists in the template directory.

For example:

```
app.get('/subdir/:pagename', function(req, res, next) {
    // Automatically & securely load 'pagename' only if 
    // '/subdir/pagename.ejs' exists in my template dir
    res.render(subdir/pagename);
});
```

I know I could just write a secure handler for this myself by striping everything that isn't A-z0-9-_ from :pagename and then checking if the file exists (and serving a 404 if it doesn't) but curious to know if there is a better way built into node.js than writing some boilerplate to handle it it.

NB: I have static pages served this way already, the only reason these pages are not static are they use the layout system to give them a common header+footer.

Will happily accept "No there isn't." as an answer if there are any Express experts or anyone who's looked into this already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been using `express` since the beginning – sorry, the answer is no. TJ did this for good reason as this functionality is specific to your use case and doesn't belong in a framework. You could look to see if anyones written a module in `npm` for this feature, but as you know, its not very hard to roll your own.

Happy Hacking! =)

Comment: I think this is quite a common use case - I could do with it on a number of totally unrelated projects and exists in request handlers in frameworks for other languages (hence asking) - but appreciate the answer :)

Comment: Hands down without a doubt a VERY common use case and I find myself adding this functionality for my apps a lot. However, the beauty of `express` is its simplicity and ability to stay out of your way. There are much more opinionated frameworks in the node world that extend `express` with these features.

Comment: Good point; while I like the simplicity of express I guess I should be considering also using frameworks with fancier routing for projects that warrant it!

Comment: Or build your own framework based on your or your teams best practices =)